# Content Security Policy - Issue to only one user

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

We have a website that has some Ajax calls within a data input form.

We recently added CSP headers from the server and the Ajax call is one among them allowing the calls.,

One of the users is seeing the below error, this has only happened to this one user and no other users within the same network are seeing issues or blockers.

**Error:**

```
Refused to connect to 'https://example/foo/bar?jsoncallback=jsonp1600112081291&userProfileId=19440&begins=%2525' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src *.example.com *.example.biz *.example1.com *.example3.com *.example4.com *.appdynamics.com *.eum-appdynamics.com *.example5.net data:".
```

Any help or advice to recreate the issue will be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Most probably he/she is using a software that my act as a proxy in his/her computer. Some antivirus app have built-in proxy. I recently encounter this similar issue with students that using computer in a lab that has proxy to connect to internet.

Answer (score 0):

> connect to 'https://example/foo/bar?jsoncallback=...

you make connect to wrong host name. You have no chances to allow such host in CSP.

> connect-src *.example.com *.example.biz *.example1.com *.example3.com
> *.example4.com *.appdynamics.com *.eum-appdynamics.com *.example5.net data:

list contains non existent domains, domains for sale. Is does not look like CSP for real website.